# How can I make indeterminate progress bar in FireMonkey (C++ Builder)?

Tags: progress-bar, c++builder, firemonkey

I want to make `indeterminate progress bar` in FireMonkey with C++ Builder? I tried `TProgressBar` but this is determinate only. I want to indeterminate like this:
[image: Progress bars]
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

FireMonkey's [`TProgressBar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.StdCtrls.TProgressBar) does not support indeterminate states. You will have to use something else, such as a [`TAniIndicator`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.StdCtrls.TAniIndicator).  This is even stated in the documentation:

> When a task with an indefinite amount of time or operations is in progress, **we recommend that you use a `TAniIndicator` to illustrate the progress**.

Otherwise, create your own custom control. Or find a 3rd party control that does what you need, for example [Yaroslav Brovin's native progress dialog components](http://www.fmxexpress.com/professional-native-progress-dialogs-for-delphi-xe8-firemonkey-on-android-and-ios/).

Comment: Thanks, there is no other way? Can I learn algoritm for `indeterminate progress bar`?